# react setting state in useeffect then trying to find something inside that state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets

I am trying to create an in-app chat but i keep stumbling across the same problem in javascript. Inside my useEffect, i make an api call to my backend to GET all the conversations with all the messages included and set that to my records state. Also in my useEffect i have a socket listener that listens to the messages sent inside the chats and would like to update the the last message preview to the new message.

My problem is when i first load the web app and try sending a message i keep getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Messages')
```

Here is my code:

```
useEffect(()=> {
            axios
            .get('/api/messages/',{headers:{"auth-token":localStorage.getItem('jwtToken')}})
                .then(res => {
                    setRecords(res.data)
                })
                .catch(err =>
                    console.log(err)      
                )

    // main socket       
    const newsocket =io.connect(CONNECTION_PORT)

      newsocket.on('connect', msg => {
          setSocket(newsocket)
          console.log(`Admin ${ADMIN.id} is waiting. socketID: ${newsocket.id}`)
       });

        newsocket.emit('waiting', ADMIN.id);

        newsocket.on("socketListening", (msg) => {
            console.log(msg)
        
            try{
                    const result = records.find(e=>e.id===msg.conversationId) //Error occurs here
                    console.log(result)
                    const resultMessages=result.Messages;      
                    const newMessages =[msg,...resultMessages]
                    result.Messages=newMessages;
                    result.lastMessage=msg.message;
                    if(msg.senderId!==ADMIN.id){
                        result.Recipient=false;
                      }else{
                        result.Recipient=true;

                      }
                    console.log(result);
                    const arraywithoutrecord = records.filter(e=>e.id!==msg.conversationId)
                    setRecords([result,...arraywithoutrecord])
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e)
            }
        })

       return(()=>newsocket.close());

    },[]);
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access a `undefined` variable.
`result` is undefined I guess. When you printing result inside the try catch what is the message. Check that.

Comment: @SivaKannan hi, the messages are getting rendered on the screen which means that my api call is working and the state is getting set. My problem is at the                     const result = records.find(e=>e.id===msg.conversationId) inside my useEffect i am not able to access the state and hence returning records as undefined

Comment: As the answer mentioned move your //main-socket code to ```useEffect( () => {
// Do your logic here
}, [records])```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like creating a useEffect that subscribes to your "records" state would do the job.

Setting a state in react can be seen as a async function, thus why you get an undefined error

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Component = () => {

  const [records, setRecords] = useState(null);
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  const CONNECTION_PORT = 1234;

  let myMsg;
  const newsocket = io.connect(CONNECTION_PORT);

  // First useEffect (called on init) :
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('/api/messages/', { headers: { 'auth-token': localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') } })
      .then(res => {
        setRecords(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err =>
        console.log(err)
      );

    // main socket
    

    newsocket.on('connect', msg => {

      // Set to component variable
      myMsg = msg;

      setSocket(newsocket);
      console.log(`Admin ${ADMIN.id} is waiting. socketID: ${newsocket.id}`);
    });

    newsocket.emit('waiting', ADMIN.id);

    newsocket.on('socketListening', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg);
    }, []);

    // Second useEffect (called every time "records" state is updated):

    useEffect(() => {


      try {

        const result = records.find(e => e.id === myMsg['conversationId']); //Error occurs here
        console.log(result);
        const resultMessages = result.Messages;
        const newMessages = [myMsg, ...resultMessages];
        result.Messages = newMessages;
        result.lastMessage = myMsg.message;

        if (myMsg['senderId'] !== ADMIN.id) {
          result.Recipient = false;
        } else {
          result.Recipient = true;
        }

        const arraywithoutrecord = records.filter(e => e.id !== myMsg['conversationId']);
        setRecords([result, ...arraywithoutrecord]);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    });

    return (() => newsocket.close());

  }, [records]);


  return (
    <></>
  );

};
```

Comment: I have tried that and it doesnt work, it keeps calling the backend every second

Comment: You shouldn't have the API call in this useEffect. Keep your useEffect as shown in your question, but create a second useEffect that subscribes to you "records" state and do you logic there. 

Does that make sense?

Comment: so,  i create a new useEffect and subscribe that to the records and just add the scoketListening event inside?

Comment: i gave it a try, now i keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'on') when trying to use socket.on("socketListening") in my 2nd useEffect

Comment: Yeah. The useEffect with the empty dependies are called "onInit" as your component gets rendered. This is where you call your API and set your respones to the "records" state. 

Then you have a second useEffect that subscribes to your "records" state (as shown in my answer), which means, that every time your "records" states gets updated, this useEffect will fire off and you can execute your logic with the actual value.

Comment: See my edit in answer

Comment: i only have 1 problem now is every time the records get updated ie. a new message gets sent, a new socket gets established. should i move     const newsocket =io.connect(CONNECTION_PORT) to the first useEffect and use socket instead of newsocket in my 2nd useEffect

Comment: I would probably put the creating of the socket outside of the useEffect and then call the ref to the socket in the useEffect that subscribes to the "records" state

Comment: Do you mind clarifying on that please?

Comment: See my edit for explanation

Comment: by "call the ref" you mean call the state correct?

Comment: No not really, more the reference to your socket. So either put it just plain in the component or in the useEffect that get called on init

Comment: i didnt get the last part sorry, also where does close socket go then?

Comment: See latest edit :)

Comment: i just gave that a try i keep getting this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'close')

Comment: Try and move the creation of the socket out of the useEffect scope (see latest edit)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248777/discussion-between-kd12345-and-gustav-vingtoft).

Comment: Where should the socket.close go, in the first useEffect or teh 2nd?

Comment: If the purpose of the socket.close is to disconnet the client from the socket, then it depends on your business logic? You can creathe a third useEffect that gets called onDestroy and close the socket there?

Comment: the solution above is not working after the edit, the socket connects multiple times not just once on page open

Answer (score -1):

records does not contain the message your are looking for. Probably it is because data are not loaded yet.

try set logs and check: what is executing first: thenLog or socketListeningLog?

```
.then(res => {
    console.log("getting is done");
    setRecords(res.data)
})
```